# I Have Solution Containing Two Project So How Can I Create Setup File For This In Vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have solution containing two project

1.) One project is Windows Service

2.) Second Project is Console Application

How can i create setup for this.

Comment: Add new project from Other project types -> Visual Studio Installer -> Setup Project